# How do I show an image in the terminal in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to just show an image along with some text. kind of like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
   
int main() 
{
     (image command)
     cout<<"Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: Very few terminals can actually show images. Were you thinking of ASCII art instead? Look at figlet (which renders text as ASCII art) or libcaca's img2txt (which renders an image as ASCII)

Comment: Does ASCII art count? Because otherwise you're out of luck (at least just in standard C++, without doing something elaborate and platform specific).

Comment: Maybe if you explain what terminal you are using someone can help with that terminal. Here is a way to do this in gnome terminal on ubuntu (sorry not in c++ code): [https://askubuntu.com/questions/797418/how-to-set-a-image-as-background-of-the-gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797418/how-to-set-a-image-as-background-of-the-gnome-terminal)

Comment: Depends on the terminal or the console.  There are terminals that can display graphics.  You'll have to dig up the specifications on that terminal to figure out how to display graphics.  If you are using a terminal emulator, verify that the emulator is set to the graphics terminal type.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way in C++ to display images.

On some operating systems, there are APIs which allow creation of graphical user interfaces. GUIs can draw images. In order to use such API, the first step is to figure out which system you are writing the program for. Next, you can read the documentation of that operating system.